# Swift lazy stored property versus regular stored property when using closure

Tags: swift, closures, lazy-evaluation

In Swift, we can set a stored property to use closure:

```
class Test {
  var prop: String = {
    return "test"
  }()
}
```

vs

or make lazy stored property use closure:

```
class Test {
  lazy var prop: String = {
    return "test"
  }()
}
```

In both cases, the code used to obtain the value for the property is only run once. It seems like they are equivalent.

When should I use lazy stored property versus computed property when using closure with it?

Comment: Actually, both are *stored properties*, not computed properties.

Comment: as Martin said, both are stored properties. the value of the first one is evaluated when an instance of class Test is created. the second one, which is lazy, is evaluated 'on demand' when its value is first time required by your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import Foundation
struct S {
    var date1: NSDate = {
        return NSDate()
    }()
    lazy var date2: NSDate = {
        return NSDate()
    }()
}

var s = S()
sleep(5)
print( s.date2, s.date1)
/* prints

2015-11-24 19:14:27 +0000 2015-11-24 19:14:22 +0000

*/
```

both are stored properties, check the real time at which they are evaluated. the lazy property is evaluated 'on demand' when first time the value is needed

Comment: Great example using the current time.

Comment: How can i check the value of the first one is evaluated when an instance of class Test is created, Swift 3 does not allow to use print func inside Struct, Thanks

Comment: @Rishi sorry, I don't understand your question, please try to explain it