# Access variable inside if statement of function

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a video play if a certain view is tapped once. The `.play()` function works well if I directly call it within an if statement inside a function (`if` which "checks" URL inside the `setupPlayerView()` function). The first functions (`setupPlayerView` and `defInteractions`) I am going to show below are going to be called in an override init which sets the properties and subviews/sublayers etc. for the video player. The last function is triggered by the second function . Pay attention to the declaration of `player` and my comment in the bottom...

## Code: func #1

```
func setupPlayerView() {

    //insert url
    let urlString = "https://blurtime.com/images/testvideo.mov"

    //check URL if can be converted to NSURL
    if let videoURL = NSURL(string: urlString){

        //player's video
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

        //add sub-layer
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.frame

        //when are frames actually rendered (when is video loaded)
        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

        //if I call player.play() here the video plays directly

    }

}
```

As I the UITapGestureRecognizers to detect a single tap I have the following function which is called in the override init as well (shortly after the previous function):

## Code: func #2

```
//set interactions
func defInteractions (){
    //enable interaction
    controlsContainerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //singletap
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTapDetected(_:)))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    //controlsContainerView
    controlsContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}
```

Now, I would like to call `player.play()` inside the function singleTapDetected which currently looks like this:

## Code: func #3

```
func singleTapDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    player.play()

}
```

However, it does not work of course as this function is outside the override init as opposed to the others and I get the error `use of unresolved identifier 'player'`. How can I call `player.play()` and get the same result as if I would call it in the first function? Can I access it within the if? I could need some help...

Comment: Make `player` a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `player` an instance variable:

```
var player: AVPlayer?
```

Then initialize it like this:

```
if self.player == nil {
    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
}
```

Then you can easily access it from anywhere in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Make the **player** property Global like this :

```
let player : AVPlayer?
```

Initialize it in **setupPlayerView()** :

```
func setupPlayerView() {

//insert url
let urlString = "https://blurtime.com/images/testvideo.mov"

//check URL if can be converted to NSURL
if let videoURL = NSURL(string: urlString){

    //player's video
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

    //add sub-layer
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.frame = self.frame

    //when are frames actually rendered (when is video loaded)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

    //if I call player.play() here the video plays directly

}

}
```

and use it like this:

```
func singleTapDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // with self
    self.player.play()

}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Declare `player` at the class level with optional.

```
var player: AVPlayer?
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `player` as a local variable in `setupPlayerView` function, you should declare it a an instance variable to be accessible in the scope of the whole class/struct.

For your case, I would suggest that instead of implementing `setupPlayerView` function, it would be a good practice to declare it as a *lazy* property , as follows:

```
lazy var player: AVPlayer? = {
    //insert url
    let urlString = "https://blurtime.com/images/testvideo.mov"

    guard let videoURL = NSURL(string: urlString) else {
        return nil
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

    //add sub-layer
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.frame = self.frame

    //when are frames actually rendered (when is video loaded)
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

    return player
}()
```

Usage:

```
// this means if the urlString is valid
if let player = player {
    player.play()
}
```

That leads to: all the needed setup for `player` should be ready *only* if needed. You might want to check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694691/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-lazy-var-in-swift).