# Image view not recognizing my tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to present a UIImagePickerController from an image and it's not working. I enable user interaction, but i still can't seem to get it working.

```
let cameraIconImageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "camera_icon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    image.tintColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 122, b: 124, a: 1 )
    image.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImage)))
    image.layer.borderWidth = 2
    image.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 122, b: 124, a: 1 ).cgColor
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

@objc func handleSelectProfileImage() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print(123)

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Use lazy variable. advantages of lazy varibale https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694691/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-lazy-var-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lazy var cameraIconImageView: UIImageView = {

let image = UIImageView()
image.image = UIImage(named: "camera_icon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
image.tintColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 122, b: 124, a: 1 )
image.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImage)))
image.layer.borderWidth = 2
image.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 122, b: 124, a: 1 ).cgColor
image.layer.cornerRadius = 20
image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
image.clipsToBounds = true
image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return image

}()
```

Use lazy in Imageview initialization.

Comment: Please who put downvote can you please explain why you downvoted. It is correct since in this if we use only lazy only self can be used inside